# Conditional variable setting in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm writing an nginx configuration that requires a proxy, and I need to original ip address. Nginx's HttpProxyModule's `$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for` variable seems perfectly adequate for the task, except that my Nginx is behind a load balance that sets not `X-Forwarded-For`, but `X-Cluster-Client-Ip`.

Now, one possibility would be using

```
set X-Forwarded-For $http_x_cluster_client_ip,$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for
```

but sometimes there *are* direct accesses to the server, which would leave a leading comma in the header. I thought about using `if`, but that scenario falls right in the middle of the cases where `if` is problematic to use.

Note that, because the client might have been proxied, I do want to preserve any data present in the `X-Forwarded-For` header, if one exists, *in addition* to passing data from `X-Cluster-Client-Ip`.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nginx HttpRealipModule to filter accesses from the Loadbalancer instead:

```
set_real_ip_from   192.168.0.1;
real_ip_header     X-Cluster-Client-Ip;
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule

Comment: That doesn't preserve `X-Forwarded-For` -- sorry if I didn't make that requisite clear.

Comment: Why not? It won't do anything to a X-Forwarded-For header, it will only rewrite the client address with the one from the X-Cluster-Client-Ip-header.

Comment: True. Maybe this is enough, though I lose the information that the request came through the load balance. I'm trying not to lose information here.

Comment: Ok, that's another requisite ;)